# How to change the color of selected tab in CSS :target Property without any Javascript?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the current tab color in CSS and the tab created using the :target property of CSS. The problem is I can't find the current clicked tab when using the :target property. So I want to show the active tab when I clicked. Also I need to show the first tab by default. Can someone help me to solve it?

Here is my code below:

```css
.tab {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.tab li {
  color: var(--dark);
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: relative;
}

.tab li:after {
  height: 1px;
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(10, 170, 219) !important;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.tab li h2 {
  font-size: inherit;
}

.tab li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

#tab .tab-content {
  display: none;
}

#tab .tab-content:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab">
  <ul class="tab">
    <li>
      <h2><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
<div id="tab1" class="tab-content">Content1</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab-content">Content2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to simulate an actual click event using only CSS is to use the checkbox. It works by attaching a label to an  element via the label's for="" attribute and using :checked attribute to detect clicked tab.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your tab switching functionality does not work. Your rules for the display of `.tab-content` are with incorrect selectors. Simply move `#tab1` and `#tab2` inside the main `#tab` element. Then the color styling will be easy.

```css
.tab {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.tab li {
  color: var(--dark);
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: relative;
}

.tab li:after {
  height: 1px;
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(10, 170, 219) !important;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.tab li h2 {
  font-size: inherit;
}

.tab li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

#tab .tab-content {
  display: none;
}

#tab .tab-content:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab">
  <ul class="tab">
    <li>
      <h2><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-content">Content1</div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">Content2</div>
</div>
```